# Django add new item to list

Tags: django

Models

```
class post(models.Model):
    post_content = models.CharField(u'Treść:', max_length=65000)
    post_thread = models.ForeignKey(thread)
    post_user = models.ForeignKey(user)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField()
    objects = post_manager()

class thread(models.Model):
    thread_title = models.CharField(u'Nazwa tematu:', max_length=100)
    thread_content = models.CharField(u'Treść:', max_length=65000)
    thread_forum = models.ForeignKey(forum, null=True)
    thread_subforum  = models.ForeignKey(subforum, null=True)
    thread_tag = models.CharField(u'Tagi', null=True,  max_length=100)
    thread_user  = models.ForeignKey(user)
    thread_date = models.DateTimeField()
    thread_write = models.BooleanField()
    thread_sticky = models.BooleanField()
    objects = thread_manager()
```

views

```
thread_list = thread.objects.select_related().filter(thread_forum_id = current_obj.id).order_by('-thread_date')
            for thread in thread_list:
                count = post.objects.select_related().filter(post_thread_id = thread.id).count()   
                thread.post = count
```

thread_list don't have post number
post have ForeignKey to thread

what I can do to get such effect?
i want add number post to to thread_list

Comment: Sorry, I know English isn't your first language -- would you mind rephrasing your question to make it easier for us to help you? I _almost_ understand what you want... :)

Answer (score 0):

You way is good. 
But there is a conflict:

```
thread_list = thread.objects.select_related().filter(thread_forum_id = current_obj.id).order_by('-thread_date')
            for thread in thread_list:
                count = post.objects.select_related().filter(post_thread_id = thread.id).count()   
                thread.post = count
```

Your class have name **thread** and your loop have name like class. 
for **thread** in thread_list:

Just do that:

```
for threads in thread_list:
                    count = post.objects.select_related().filter(post_thread_id = threads.id).count()   
                    threads.post = count
```

or something like this. Just change loop - i add 's' at the end of a word